# Blazor .NET 8 not displaying the image due to a route issue

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-8.0

"When I define the Route as follows, images no longer load for me.
.NET 8 and Blazor app

@page "/"
@page "/{type}/{text}"

Answer (score 0):

try add  a route constraint with `Route` attribute  to avoid static files match your route,modify `@page "/{type}/{text}"` to

```
@attribute [Route("/{type:nonfile}/{text:nonfile}")]
```